# How can I exit jekyll's site local preview mode in GitShell

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

After evaluate the `Jekyll serve`, I can see the site in localhost:4000

[image]
but how to exit the preview mode?

Of course I can close the GitShell and reopen it to cd into directory and re-build to preview, but boring.

Comment: Please don't close this question. It's not really a Jekyll question, but I can see other Jekyll users that aren't that familiar with the terminal having similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "preview mode"?

Do you just want `Ctrl + C` to terminate? If I understand you correctly, this has nothing to do with Jekyll I reckon, it's a basic operation the command line interface.

Comment: thanks, that's the shortcut I wanna, so should I delete the post? too simple

Comment: fine, should wait 5 minute.